# Why add namespace into inner function in php?

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces

In Symfony, some functions have a root namespace and some functiona do not, why?

For example:

```
// code from symfony 
if (file_exists($cache->getPath()) && \is_object($this->container = include $cache->getPath())) {
     $this->container->set('kernel', $this);
     $oldContainer = $this->container;
     $fresh = true;
 }
```

`file_exists` does not have a namespace, but `\is_object` does.

I've noticed that this sort of difference occurs throughout the whole Symfony project.

Comment: I've seen a lot of automated code quality tools that promote either the one or the other, but this is just weird. Very interested in the answer.

Comment: Both are standard PHP functions and are defined under the root `\\` namespace. Hence not giving any namespace should work in both cases. I'm assuming Symfony has redefined the function __is_object__ and hence is specifying the namespace to call the PHP's function, instead of their own

Comment: The main difference is the file_exists function can be defined (and replaced) in the current namespace, but \is_object will always refer to the root function (native php).

Comment: I've noticed, have no regular when use root namespace for root function  in Symfony, one function have it in some Class , but dose not in other Class also.I have no idea about this.

Answer (score 2):

This could most likely be to get the performance improvements that were introduced to some functions in PHP 7.0 where some functions where replaced by opcodes. In order to get these improvements these functions have to be referenced to by the root namespace.

[This issue](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/3048) on the PHP-CS-Fixer GitHub repository includes a comment with a list of functions that use this. `file_exists` has not been improved in this manner so it will yield no performance improvement to reference it by the root namespace. This issue was also referenced many times by PRs for the Symfony GitHub repository.

[Here is a link](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f2db305fa4e9bd7d04d567822687ec714aedcdb5/Zend/zend_compile.c#L3872) to the PHP source code where you can also find the list of functions with this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you very much